# Convert NTSC DVD to Raw HEVC File - 29.97 or 23.967 fps?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I want to use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) to convert an NTSC DVD `.m2v` file to a raw `.hevc` file.

---

### Framerate

Viewing the `m2v`'s fps properties in different software gives different reports:

```
Windows         29.97
VLC             29.97
MPC-BE          29.97
Media Info      23.976
Adobe Premiere  23.976
FFprobe         59.94
```

**FFprobe**

```
[streams.stream.0]
codec_name=mpeg2video
codec_time_base=1001/30000
r_frame_rate=60000/1001
avg_frame_rate=30000/1001
time_base=1/1200000
field_order=progressive
```

---

### FFmpeg

I'm guessing the original footage before being put on the DVD was filmed at `23.976`.

When converting to `.hevc` should I be converting down to `23.976` or leave it at `29.97` like the source file?

**Script**

```
ffmpeg

-fflags +genpts 

-framerate ntsc 

-i input.m2v 

-c:v libx265 
-preset medium -x265-params "fps=24000/1001"
-pix_fmt yuv420p 

-copyts 
-avoid_negative_ts make_zero 

-vf "fps=24000/1001" 

-f hevc 

output.hevc
```

Comment: How many frames does this output - `ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i input.m2v -copyts -vf "showinfo" -vsync 0 -t 100 -f null -` ?

Comment: @Gyan At the end of the parse it says `frame= 2398 fps=225`

Comment: Frame rate is 24000/1001.

Comment: @Gyan Am I using the correct FFmpeg commands to convert to 23.976? If I don't convert and leave default it ends up 29.97.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input appears to be `24000/1001` based on the null decode results.

Use

```
ffmpeg

-fflags +genpts 
-framerate 24000/1001 

-i input.m2v 

-vf "fps=24000/1001,format=yuv420p"

-c:v libx265 
-preset medium -x265-params "fps=24000/1001"

output.hevc
```

`.hevc` has no timestamps so copyts / avoid_negative_ts has no relevance.